# Swapped device orientation axis when working with sencha/phonegap on android

Tags: javascript, android, sencha-touch-2, device-orientation

I am writing an application using Sencha Touch/Phonegap which uses the javascript to retreive the orientation of the device (given in degrees around the device axis):

```
 window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function (event) {

        //use event.alpha, event.beta, event.gamma
    }, false);
```

I have also set the screen orientation of the device to landscape, using the android manifest file.

The code works fine, so far, but on specific devices (for example Galaxy Tab), two of the axis are swapped. I assume that this is some issue regarding the default orientation of the device (landscape vs portrait), but I do not know how to get the default orientation using javascript.

How could I solve this problem?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try: Ext.Viewport.getOrientation()

Comment: Yes, I did. Unfortunately, this way I can only find out what the current, but not the default orientation is.